# How to transfer a file/files from one S3 bucket/directory to another using AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I would like to transfer a file (i.e copy it to a target directory and delete it from the source directory) from one S3 bucket directory to another using AWS data pipeline.

I tried using the ShellCommandActivity and made a script that would move a file/files from one S3 bucket/directory to another. But the result was that it only copied it to the target S3 bucket/directory and did not remove the file in the S3 source directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove something from an S3 bucket you must explicitly delete it; there is no native concept of "move" other than copy and delete.

That said, last time I tried I found I could not delete from an S3 bucket resource in the data pipeline. I had to get around this by using s3cmd instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Did you run the s3cmd in the ShellCommandActivity in a data pipeline?

Comment: Can you share how you did that?

Comment: There's really nothing to share: just set up a ShellCommandActivity and put the commands you want to execute in it or have it run a shell script stored on S3.

Comment: Hi, I have a shell script stored in S3 containing the following command:
#!/bin/bash
s3cmd mv ${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR}/* ${OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR}/;

I tried running the command locally and it works fine. But when I tried to run the script in AWS data pipeline, I'm getting the following error:
Cause: Script returned with exit status 127
Can you help check what is wrong or lacking in my script or in my data pipeline.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you use/create a Task Runner to run your ShellCommandActivity?